# how to round a float number to the nearest integer in Python

Tags: python

The function round(x) in Python yields floating number. Therefore, what is the most appropriate code in Python to round a float to the nearest neighbor?

Comment: neighboring integer? `int(round(x))`

Comment: @falsetru I think you mean `int(round(x))`, no?

Comment: @JonSurrell, You're right.

Answer (score 25):

It seems that round already does what you want, or maybe I did not understand the question.

```
>>> round(3.2)
3
>>> round(3.8)
4

>>> a = round(3.8)
>>> type(a)
<class 'int'>
```

**EDIT**

Python3 round returns an integer, but in Python2.7 round returns a float. For Python2.7 just do:

```
int(round(x))
```

Comment: In python 3, round(1.5) = 2 but round(2.5) = 2

Comment: Indeed, print( round(1.5), round(2.5) ) prints 2 2 . python 3.8. Unbelievable.

Comment: @BertBril This is the [documented](https://docs.python.org/release/3.8.5/library/functions.html#round) behavior. For floats ending in .5 it rounds towards an even integer.

Comment: @FractalLotus Wow - yes I see now. Nice illustration that decisions made by the language designers can have far-reaching consequences. This choice may have its advantages in some areas, it will lead to very hard to find strangeness in other areas. Personally, I don't like the 'documented' behavior - odd or even numbers deciding the outcome? Almost ... creepy.

Comment: For some (mostly Russian-educated?) that is just the normal correct way to round a number. If you want exactly the interval (up to an integer shift) for each value, you can always use math.floor( 0.5 + x ).